# CASE WHEN to calculate tax on a tier based tax system

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table with user incomes and i wish to calculate their income tax percentage based on that income. The issue is that the tax rate is different for each bracket e.g.:

```
MinLimit| MaxLimit| TaxRate
0       | 14000   | 10.50
14001   | 48000   | 17.50
48001   | 70000   | 30.00
70001   | 1000000 | 33.00
```

So if the income of 1 person is 49,000 then they would be taxed as follows:

```
14000 * 0.1050 = 1470
34000 * 0.1750 = 5950 (34,000 is income between 14k -48k)
1000  * 0.30   = 300  (1000 is remaining income)
total = 1470 + 5950 + 300 = 7720
```

I am running on SQL Server 2017 Express. I have tried running a chained CASE-WHEN statement i.e.

```
CASE WHEN
     THEN

     WHEN
     THEN 
and so on...
```

but I can figure out how to add the logic of subtracting the remaining amount. Please find my code below.

```
SELECT 'emp_name' AS 'Director', 
SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) AS 'INCOME',
CASE WHEN (SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) < 14000)
     THEN ((SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) - 14000) * 0.1050)

     WHEN (SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) > 14000 and (SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) < 48001))
     THEN (((SUM(ABS([Transaction Amount])) - 14000) * 0.1050) - 48000) * 0.1750 end AS 'Income Tax'
FROM Transactions
```

EDIT 1:
Input Data:

```
Transaction Type| PAYEE  | Transaction Amount
DEBIT           | DEBIT  | -184.00
CREDIT          | CREDIT | 4000.00
...
```

Output Data:

```
Director | INCOME  | Income Tax
emp_name | 45100.00| NULL
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong or if my thinking is incorrect.

Comment: Could you write the input data and output data?

Comment: @StepUp added input/ouput :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery may be the simplest to read and understand:

```
declare @t table (MinLimitExclusive int, MaxLimitInclusive int, TaxRate decimal(5,2))
insert into @t(MinLimitExclusive,MaxLimitInclusive,TaxRate) values
(0    ,14000  , 10.50),
(14000,48000  , 17.50),
(48000,70000  , 30.00),
(70000,1000000, 33.00)

declare @transactions table (Income decimal(10,2))
insert into @transactions (Income) values (49000)

select
    (Income - MinLimitExclusive) * TaxRate / 100 +
    (select SUM((rates2.MaxLimitInclusive - rates2.MinLimitExclusive) * rates2.TaxRate / 100) 
    from @t rates2 where rates2.MaxLimitInclusive <= rates.MinLimitExclusive)

from
    @transactions tr
        inner join
    @t rates
        on
            tr.Income > rates.MinLimitExclusive and tr.Income <= rates.MaxLimitInclusive
```

It's remarkably simplified when you realise that the only maths you need to do related to the actual income is related to the bracket it actually fits in - all of the lower rate brackets, by implication, were used in their entirety so you can compute those other taxes purely from the rates table.

I've changed your rates data slightly to make the computations straightforward and not need lots of `+/-1` adjustments.

Comment: Thanks @Damien --> used your code as inspiration and with some slight modifications it worked. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you start with a MinLimit of 1 instead of 0. The rest of the calculation is straight forward:

```
declare @taxslabs table (minlimit int, maxlimit int, taxrate decimal(18, 2));
insert into @taxslabs values
(1,     14000,   10.50),
(14001, 48000,   17.50),
(48001, 70000,   30.00),
(70001, 1000000, 33.00);

select persons.*, taxslabs.*, taxableamount, taxableamount * taxrate / 100 as taxamount
from (values
    (1, 49000),
    (2, 70000),
    (3, 70001)
) as persons(id, income)
cross join @taxslabs as taxslabs
cross apply (select case when income <= maxlimit then income else maxlimit end - minlimit + 1) as ca(taxableamount)
where minlimit <= income
```

You can place this query inside a subquery and use `GROUP BY ... SUM()` or `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY)` to calculate the sum of taxes.

Sample output:

```
| id | income | minlimit | maxlimit | taxrate | taxableamount | taxamount        |
|----|--------|----------|----------|---------|---------------|------------------|
| 1  | 49000  | 1        | 14000    | 10.50   | 14000         | 1470.000000      |
| 1  | 49000  | 14001    | 48000    | 17.50   | 34000         | 5950.000000      |
| 1  | 49000  | 48001    | 70000    | 30.00   | 1000          | 300.000000       |
| 2  | 70000  | 1        | 14000    | 10.50   | 14000         | 1470.000000      |
| 2  | 70000  | 14001    | 48000    | 17.50   | 34000         | 5950.000000      |
| 2  | 70000  | 48001    | 70000    | 30.00   | 22000         | 6600.000000      |
| 3  | 70001  | 1        | 14000    | 10.50   | 14000         | 1470.000000      |
| 3  | 70001  | 14001    | 48000    | 17.50   | 34000         | 5950.000000      |
| 3  | 70001  | 48001    | 70000    | 30.00   | 22000         | 6600.000000      |
| 3  | 70001  | 70001    | 1000000  | 33.00   | 1             | 0.330000         |
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this relevant query using group by on transaction table and join to rate taxe table can be down excepted result :

```
CREATE TABLE #Transaction  
(
    tID             int PRIMARY KEY,  
    tIdUser         varchar(50),
    Amount          decimal(9,3)
 );  
CREATE TABLE #RefTaxe  
(
    pID             int PRIMARY KEY, 
    minLimit        int, 
    maxLImit        int,
    rate            decimal(9,3)
); 




INSERT INTO #Transaction 
SELECT 1, 'User1', 1259.3
UNION
SELECT 2, 'User1', 10259.3
UNION
SELECT 3, 'User3', 30581.3
UNION 
SELECT 4, 'User2', 75000.36
UNION 
SELECT 5, 'User2', 15000.36
UNION 
SELECT 6, 'User4', 45000.36
UNION 
SELECT 7, 'User4', 5000.36


INSERT INTO #RefTaxe 
select 1,0,14000,10.50
UNION
SELECT 2,14001,48000,17.50
UNION
SELECT 3,48001,70000,30.00
UNION
SELECT 4,70001,1000000,33.00


-- SELECT * FROM #Transaction

-- SELECT * FROM #RefTaxe

--  SELECT tIdUser,SUM(AMOUNT) as SumAmount, CAST(FLOOR(SUM(AMOUNT))as int) as SumAsInt     FROM #Transaction GROUP BY tIdUser
/***/
-- Perform select 
/***/
SELECT tIdUser, SumAmount as 'DetaxedAmount' ,SumAmount * (rate/100) as TaxOfAmount, SumAmount+ SumAmount * (rate/100) as TaxedAmount
FROM #RefTaxe RT    
JOIN (
    SELECT tIdUser,SUM(AMOUNT) as SumAmount,  CAST(FLOOR(SUM(AMOUNT))as int) as SumAsInt
    FROM #Transaction GROUP BY tIdUser
)   AS GroupedTR ON RT.minLimit <= SumAsInt AND RT.maxLImit >= SumAsInt


/***/

DROP TABLE #Transaction
DROP TABLE #RefTaxe
```

Result output :

```
tIdUser DetaxedAmount   TaxOfAmount     TaxedAmount
User1   11518.600     1209.453000      12728.053
User2   90000.720     29700.237600     119700.958
User3   30581.300     5351.727500      35933.028
User4   50000.720     15000.216000     65000.936
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Query is calculating very exact results against tax rules define by Pakistan Government.[Thanks & Regards - Noman Ali].**

```
Select 
Salary, 
Salary*12 as YearlySalary,
case 
when salary * 12 Between 600001 and 1200000 then ((salary * 12 - 600000) / 100 * 2.5) / 12
when salary * 12 Between 1200001 and 2400000 then (15000 + (salary * 12 - 1200000) / 100 * 12.50) / 12   
when salary * 12 Between 2400001 and 3600000 then (165000 + (salary * 12 - 2400000) / 100 * 20.0)   / 12
when salary * 12 Between 3600001 and 6000000 then (405000 + (salary * 12 - 3600000) / 100 * 25.0 )  / 12
when salary * 12 Between 6000001 and 12000000 then (1005000 + (salary* 12 - 6000000) / 100 * 32.5 ) / 12
when salary * 12 >  12000001 then (2955000 + (salary * 12 - 12000000) / 100 * 35.0 ) / 12
else 0 end as IncomeTax
from Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
PayrollNum, MAX(data.TaxablePay) AS TaxablePay,
SUM(taxable_income * TaxRate) AS PAYE
FROM Pyrtrn_Payroll AS data

INNER JOIN PyrMd_PayeeTaxlabs tb ON data.TaxablePay > tb.MinPay
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT
CASE WHEN data.TaxablePay >= tb.MaxPay THEN tb.MaxPay - tb.MinPay
ELSE data.TaxablePay - tb.MinPay END AS taxable_income
) AS ComputeSection

GROUP BY PayrollNum

Important Tables:

Pyrtrn_Payroll your table with the TaxablePay

PyrMd_PayeeTaxlabs format
MinPay MaxPay Taxrate
1   24000   0.100
24001   40000   0.200
40001   90000   0.250
90001   15000   0.300